# __get_user_pages failed to pin page. In which scenario it's failed to pin pages

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, dma

In which scenarios __get_user_pages() failed and how to tackle if failed

In this function find_extend_vma returns null

Comment: Means you either gave it a bad address or a page with bad permissions (like asking for write access to a read-only page).

Comment: Of course it would also fail if not called in user context.